# JavaFX ListView custom cells

Tags: listview, javafx, fxml

I have tried to create custom cells for a ListView but nothing appears...

There is my Menu Controller where i use the ListView witch must contain projects :

FXML (Just a blank page to test) :

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="root" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.exalow.easymind.ui.factory.ProjectCell" />
```

```
public class MenuController extends Controller implements Initializable {
 
    private final ListView<Project> projectListView = new ListView<>();
 
    public MenuController(EasyMind api, Stage stage) {
        super(api, stage);
    }
 
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
 
        ObservableList<Project> observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        observableList.addAll(api.getProjects());
        projectListView.setItems(observableList);
 
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/fxml/ProjectCell.fxml"));
 
        try {
            loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 
        projectListView.setCellFactory(cellFactory -> loader.getController());
    }
```

And there my Cell Controller

```
public class ProjectCell extends ListCell<Project> implements Initializable {
 
    private Project project;
 
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane root;
 
    @FXML
    private ImageView imageView;
 
    @FXML
    private Label nameLabel;
 
    @FXML
    private Label descriptionLabel;
 
    @FXML
    private Label createDateLabel;
 
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        setGraphic(root);
    }
 
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Project item, boolean empty) {
 
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
 
        if (empty || item == null) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
 
            if (project.hasImage()) {
                imageView.setImage(new Image(project.getImageUrl()));
            } else imageView.setImage(new Image(project.getDefaultImage()));
 
            nameLabel.setText(item.getName());
            descriptionLabel.setText(item.getDescription());
            createDateLabel.setText(item.getCreateDate().toString());
        }
 
        this.project = item;
    }
}
```

I have no error but there is no cells in my ListView when i open the application.

Reproducible Example :

Any ProjectCell are created...

```
public class ProjectCellController {

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane root;

    @FXML
    private ImageView imageView;

    @FXML
    private Label nameLabel;

    @FXML
    private Label descriptionLabel;

    @FXML
    private Label createDateLabel;

    private Project project;

    public void setProject(Project project) {

        if (project.hasImage()) {
            imageView.setImage(new Image(project.getImageUrl()));
        } else imageView.setImage(new Image(project.getDefaultImage()));

        nameLabel.setText(project.getName());
        descriptionLabel.setText(project.getDescription());
        createDateLabel.setText(project.getCreateDate().toString());

        this.project = project;
    }
}
```

```
public class ProjectCell extends ListCell<Project> {

    private AnchorPane root;

    private ProjectCellController controller;

    public ProjectCell() {

        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/fxml/ProjectCell.fxml"));
            root = loader.load();
            controller = loader.getController();
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exc);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Project project, boolean empty) {
        if (empty || project == null) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            controller.setProject(project);
            setGraphic(root);
        }
    }
}
```

And FXML (A basic blank anchore pane) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane fx:id="root" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.exalow.easymind.ui.controllers.ProjectCellController" />
```

Comment: Please post the "controller" (which doesn't seem like a controller), and the FXML, in the question, not as a separate link. This looks like you are trying to use the same UI instance in every cell, which certainly won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many issues with your code.

1. You are assigning the same cell instance to every cell (because your cell factory returns the same instance every time it is invoked). This violates the rule that UI elements can only be added to a scene graph once.
2. If `updateItem()` is invoked on an empty cell, you set the graphic to null. Under no circumstances do you ever set the graphic back to anything else. So if a cell is *ever* used as an empty cell (and this typically happens when the `ListView` is first created or displayed), then it will have no content for all time, even if it becomes non-empty later.
3. A controller typically should not be a UI component. There are some exceptions to this rule (e.g. using the [custom component pattern](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components)), but it's generally a bad idea as it confuses controllers and views.

So the strategy here should be to set the cell factory to a factory that creates a new cell instance. That cell can load the FXML file in the constructor (so each cell loads a new instance of the UI, but each cell loads it only once). In the `updateItem()` method set the graphic to null if the cell is empty, otherwise configure the controller based on the item and set the graphic to the UI loaded from the FXML.

Something like:

```
public class ProjectCellController  {
 
 
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane root;
 
    @FXML
    private ImageView imageView;
 
    @FXML
    private Label nameLabel;
 
    @FXML
    private Label descriptionLabel;
 
    @FXML
    private Label createDateLabel;
 
    public void setProject(Project project) {
        if (project.hasImage()) {
            imageView.setImage(new Image(project.getImageUrl()));
        } else imageView.setImage(new Image(project.getDefaultImage()));
 
        nameLabel.setText(project.getName());
        descriptionLabel.setText(project.getDescription());
        createDateLabel.setText(project.getCreateDate().toString());
    }
}
```

Then

```
public class ProjectCell extends ListCell<Project> {

    private AnchorPane root ;
    private ProjectCellController controller ;

    public ProjectCell() {

        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/fxml/ProjectCell.fxml"));
            root = loader.load();
            controller = loader.getController();
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            // this is basically fatal, so just bail here:
            throw new RuntimeException(exc);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Project project, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(project, empty);
        if (empty || project == null) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            controller.setProject(project);
            setGraphic(root);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, change the `fx:controller` attribute of the FXML file accordingly, and set the controller factory:

```
projectListView.setCellFactory(listView -> new ProjectCell());
```

---

Here is a simplified but complete example:

Project.java:

```
public class Project {
    private final String name ;
    public Project(String name) {
        this.name = name ;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name ;
    }
}
```

Main.fxml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>

<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="MainController">
   <center>
      <ListView fx:id="list" />
   </center>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
   </padding>
</BorderPane>
```

MainController.java:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;

public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private ListView<Project> list ;
    
    public void initialize() {
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 100 ; i++) {
            list.getItems().add(new Project("Project "+i));
        }
        list.setCellFactory(lv -> new ProjectCell());
    }
}
```

ProjectCell.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;

public class ProjectCell extends ListCell<Project> {

    private Parent root ;
    private ProjectCellController controller ;
    
    public ProjectCell() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ProjectCell.fxml"));
            root = loader.load();
            controller = loader.getController() ;
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exc);
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Project project, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(project, empty);
        if (empty || project==null) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            controller.setProject(project);
            setGraphic(root);
        }
    }
}
```

ProjectCell.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>

<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ProjectCellController">
    <children>
        <Label fx:id="nameLabel" />
    </children>
</VBox>
```

ProjectCellController.java:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class ProjectCellController {

    @FXML
    private Label nameLabel ;
    
    public void setProject(Project project) {
        nameLabel.setText(project.getName());
    }
}
```

and the main application class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;


public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Scene scene = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml")), 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

Comment: I have done what you said but like before no errors but nothing appears... IDK what to do :(

Comment: @Exalow Then you need to post an actual [mre] in the question, so other people can copy, paste, and run it to see the issue.

Comment: @Exalow It works fine for me: I posted a complete example which you can test. No-one can really help you any further without a [mre].

Comment: @Exalow You need to post a complete example that we can copy and run. I don't know what you're not understanding about that. I have posted a complete example in my answer that you can copy and run and verify it works. I don't know what else you're expecting anyone else to do.

Comment: Oh my... Literally after 3 hours i found that was beacause my ListView was final, I want to cry. Thanks you for helping :)

Comment: @Exalow this is exactly why you should post a [mre]. It would be picked up very quickly.